# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException while adding reminder in calendar

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, reminders

```
 @SuppressLint({"RxLeakedSubscription", "RxSubscribeOnError"})
public static long pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDate, boolean needReminder) {
    /***************** Event: note(without alert) *******************/

    ContentResolver cr = curActivity.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, startDate);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, addInfo);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, startDate);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Asia/Calcutta");
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Uri uriEvent = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uriEvent.getLastPathSegment());
    try {
        if (needReminder) {
            ContentResolver crreminder = curActivity.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues valuesreminder = new ContentValues();
            valuesreminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
            valuesreminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 15);
            valuesreminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Uri uri = crreminder.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, valuesreminder);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return eventID;
}
```

**The error i am getting in logs is**

```
2019-03-06 16:29:16.935 23021-23021/com.medikoe.connect.debug W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
2019-03-06 16:29:16.936 23021-23021/com.medikoe.connect.debug
```

Event id is created successfully but while inserting uri for reminder is creating sqlite exception . Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> Update:  I found that this error can be occurred with in two conditions.

1. If you didn't config your google calendar app in your
   phone/emulator this error will occur. Then make sure that you configure the google calendar app with a gmail account before running the app.
2. If you are passing wrong formatted or false time to the event or reminder. use unix time with correct time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also faced same issue. Finally, I found the solution.

First of all, you have to find all logged in gmail id from the device and then select any one gmail account and find its calendar id. After that you have to pass that id to the event query like this....

> **values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);**

**at last call you function**

**See below method for finding email id's...**

```
 public static Hashtable listCalendarId(Context context) {

    try {
        if (haveCalendarReadWritePermissions((Activity) context)) {

            String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
            Uri calendars;
            calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

            ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
            Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);

            if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String calName;
                String calID;
                int cont = 0;
                int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
                int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                Hashtable<String, String> calendarIdTable = new Hashtable<>();
                do {
                    calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
                    calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
                    Log.v(TAG, "CalendarName:" + calName + " ,id:" + calID);
                    calendarIdTable.put(calName, calID);
                    cont++;
                } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());

                managedCursor.close();

                return calendarIdTable;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```